# How do I serve my mern app in production with docker using nginx?

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, webpack, mern

I am trying to serve my mern stack app using nginx in production. I have a Dockerfile:

```
# build environment
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
# new
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

a docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    depends_on: 
      - mongo

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

volumes: 
  node_modules:
  data:
```

and this is my scripts portion of my package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "development": "nodemon",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.client.production.js && webpack --mode=production --config webpack.config.server.js",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node ./dist/server.generated.js"
  },
```

However when I start the container only docker-compose logs are for mongo and nginx only shows the default page.
This is my nginx.conf

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

}
```

Note: this setup works when I used create react app (only I replaced dist by build). This project is using server side rendering. I don't know what I am doing wrong but I would sure appreciate any thoughts. The project is located here: https://github.com/smeyerhot/mern-market the only difference is the docker-compose, Dockerfile and nginx/nginx.conf files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you try to serve a nodejs app and not a static app. It's why you don't need the nginx server.

I think you should change the Dockerfile for:

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build
CMD npm run start
```

The only problem here it's that you will have all the build dependencies on your image.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it not an advantage to serve the static assets via nginx? When I run locally I use node to serve the react. I guess I would only use nginx if I had a separate backend and frontend? ie. two separate processes.

Comment: You can use nginx to serve static content but here, it's not only static content as the nodejs process will do some server side rendering.